# Use inline variable like '@rownum' query in HQL with mysql db

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql, rownum

I want spring hql query for below mysql query -

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT `Emp_Id`, `Emp_Name`, `Dept`,
           CASE `Dept`
              WHEN @curDept THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
              ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curDept := Dept 
           END as RANK
    FROM Table1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curDept := '') r
    ORDER BY `Dept`, `Emp_Name`
    ) t
ORDER BY RANK, `Dept`
```

Table Data -

```
       
Emp_Id  Emp_Name    Dept
1       aa          111
2       bb          222
3       cc          333
4       dd          222
5       ee          111
6       ff          333
7       gg          222
8       hh          111
9       ii          333
10      jj          222
```

Expected Output Result -

```
Emp_Id  Emp_Name    Dept
1           aa          111
2           bb          222
3           cc          333
5           ee          111
4           dd          222
6           ff          333
8           hh          111
7           gg          222
9           ii          333
10          jj          222
```

I want query should fetch all rows of table, but sorting should be according to dept column, that too without grouping.

Please find attached image for specification -
[Table data and expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYnBF.png)
Thanks in Advance